# very simple media query not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I have copied some media query code from elsewhere which works absolutely fine, but when incorporating into my own project, it doesn't seem to work.

I've looked at previous stackoverflow questions, and tried implementing the fixes or tests such as,

checking whether the media query is working by applying an unwanted background color, which fails. I've also made sure to add the viewport metatag.

Here is my media query

```
/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) { 

body { margin: 5px; width: 5px; }

.testimonial {

            background-color: black;
        }


 }
```

The live page can be seen here (click on testimonials, and then click on a picture): http://krmmalik.com/me/

**update:** Just spoke to a colleague and he seems to think that the reason the media queries are not working is because the testimonials content is being loaded in an iframe at which point the media detection doesn't take place?

Comment: What size screen are you testing with?  What does your viewport meta look like? Are you in landscape or portrait?

Comment: Just curious, isn't the max width usually 480?

Comment: your code shows that its `.testimonials`  with the S and it is an id - just wondering if its a typo or mistake

Comment: @MikeBrant I'm testing with an iPhone, in portrait mode.

viewport information is as follows

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Comment: @xivo I've checked for the type and the class name is correct without the S

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it work perfectly.
why would you set the body width to 5px, if the max-width should be 479px?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px){
   body { 
     margin: 5px;
   }
   .testimonial {
     background-color: #000;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Tried this, still doesnt work for me. Have cleared cache on the mobile browser as well, and still no luck. What device did you test with?

I set the body width to 5px just as a test to see if it would effect the page in any way, but on my device i'm not seeing any changes.

Comment: I've also tried - @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), 
       only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)